# How can I effectively render components at regular intervals in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing a kind of funnel application with chat using low react.

The main thing is that when rendering the chat message, I want to use the
chat messages need to be rendered for multiple conditions.

***Below are the rendering conditions***

1. when there are 2 or more messages with writer 'employee' in a row (when updated), each message should be rendered 1 second apart.
2. whenever a Step changes, a loading message must be shown for 2 seconds. For example, to finalize a particular Step and update to the next Step, the loading bubble must be shown for 2 seconds before the state is updated to the next Step.
3. Always render the loading bubble for at least 2 seconds when the user types and sends. This may take longer than 2 seconds and the loading bubble may be displayed for a longer period of time due to the logic of API calls, validation, etc.
4. All loading bubbles should be displayed for the required amount of time before being removed.

Below is an example of the code I implemented.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bshapb?file=src%2FuseStep.ts,src%2FuseInitStep.ts,src%2Findex.tsx,src%2Fdatas.ts

In my code, I'm adjusting the message store to update with new messages every 1 second.
We want to add a flag called addLoading to show a loading message for 2 seconds when moving to a new step, but this is not working properly.

Also, the loading message that is shown on user input is automatically added on user input, and the remaining loading message is removed when the next employee message comes in.

However, we're using setTimeout in several places in our code to manage when to render, expose loading messages, and move Steps, making it complicated and unmanageable.
In our example, we have 4 steps, but in reality, we have about 20 steps.

To meet all of the rendering conditions mentioned above
I've tried more advanced methods like custom hooks and message queues to ensure that messages are rendered at regular intervals and that loading messages are shown and removed at the desired time, but I'm not familiar enough with React to solve this yet.

If you have any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

It’s a bit hard to answer such a broad question, but here is some advice:

- do not represent "loading messages" as a special kind of message, otherwise you risk having several of them, having them in between other messages, etc. Instead, represent it simply as a top-level `isLoading` boolean in your state. Your React components can still represent it as a blue box, of course, but this way you're guaranteed that there is at most one and that it is always at the end.
- I’m not sure what your 20 steps look like (I’m guessing some steps depend on the answers to the previous steps?), but I would not define a separate hook for each step. Instead I would try to first describe the whole step logic (in which order do the steps come, which messages they contain, etc.) as a plain Javascript object, if possible, and then write a generic custom hook that can handle any possible step. Otherwise you will repeat yourself a lot.
- `setTimeout` is perfectly fine, you should use it, although ideally the whole timeout logic will be encapsulated in just a few reusable hooks so you won’t need to add more calls to `setTimeout` if you add more steps.

PS: you are using the word "rendering" in a confusing/incorrect way. You do not want to influence rendering, which is something that happens automatically in React, instead you simply want to change state at regular intervals (and React will automatically rerender).